# protected pages: open different pages based on user type

Tags: wordpress, passwords

There 2 types of pages on my wordpress site. 
Each type is relevant to separate groups of usertype.

Both pages are password protected.

The problem is this - I would like to have one common access page to the protected content. 
So the browser should click on the "login page" and then be redirected to their relevant content based on the usertype.

Is there a way to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1):

You should try [Paid Memberships Pro](http://wordpress.org/plugins/paid-memberships-pro/) plugin with Flexible content control by Membership Level, Reports, Affiliates and Discounts.
You Can select Pages according to their user types, easily.

In Which you can Set up unlimited membership levels and provide restricted access to pages, posts, categories, videos, forums, downloads, support, single "a la carte" page access, and more. Paid Memberships Pro is flexible enough to fit the needs of almost all online and offline businesses. It works great out of the box, but is easy for developers to customize to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out!

[Members plugin](http://themehybrid.com/plugins/members)  - to make and assign user groups and roles

[Simple Modal login](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-login/) for users to log in

[Peter's Login Redirect plugin](http://www.theblog.ca/wplogin-redirect) -  to redirect the users to the relevant page on login